# Known sum of unknown number of dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A random number $N$ of dice are thrown, with $\Pr(N=i)=2^{-i} \ ; \ i \ge 1$
>
> Let $S$ be the sum of the faces after $N$ dice are thrown.
>
> $\Pr(N=2|S=4)$?

My work:

$$\Pr(N=2|S=4) = \frac{\Pr(N=2 \cap S=4)}{\Pr(S=4)}$$

$$=\frac{\Pr(N=2 \cap S=4)}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty{\Pr(S=4|N=i)}}$$

and maybe the denominator is some geometric series?

Comment: The denominator is the sum of $4$ positive terms (if you throw $n$ dice then the sum can be from $n$ to $6n$) but it should be $\sum_{i=1}^4\Pr(S=4 \cap N=i)$ or $\sum_{i=1}^4\Pr(S=4 \mid N=i)\Pr(N=i)$

Comment: Ah, of course, there's only a finite number of cases to consider, not infinite! If you post that as your answer I'll accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As requested in comments*

Hints:

- The denominator is the sum of $4$ positive terms; if you throw $n$ dice then the sum can be from $n$ to $6n$, so a score of $4$ cannot have involve more than $4$ dice
- The denominator should be $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4\Pr(S=4 \cap N=i)$, i.e.   $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4\Pr(S=4 \mid N=i)\Pr(N=i)$